# Where to install library for Java on Ubuntu command line

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the Charva tutorial to work, but I don't think I'm installing it correctly. I added the .jar files to /jre/lib/ext, but I get this error when I try to run the tutorial file:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Tutorial (wrong name: tutorial/java/Tutorial)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Am I supposed to be running something else when I compile or am I installing the library the wrong way?

Comment: Add it to the classpath.

Comment: Is it failing to find the library or is this error saying something else?

Comment: This error is saying that Java cannot find the class you are referencing in the byte code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `.jar` files to the classpath using:

```
java -cp "Charva.jar" main.Class
```

If you need to add multiple jars, or you want it to be better structured in folders, put the jars under `lib` which is the common thing to do, and use:

```
java -cp "lib/*.jar" main.Class
```

If you're using and IDE, tag the question with the specific IDE to get specific instructions for your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you build and run your program in your IDE.

Once you have a working program you can build a JAR and when you specify it on the command line with

```
java -cp {path-to-my-jar}.jar mypackage.MyClass
```

you can put the JAR where ever you like.